# ReactJS ES6 building a TODO small project blocker in rendering elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a small TODO list project and I hit the wall. I created a form that is responsible for adding new tasks on the list. It consists of two inputs - one for the task name and the other one for the description. There's also an image submit input.

The problem is that only the first item is appended. Another entries just replace the current one. I was trying to somehow gather all of these into one array and map but was unsuccessful. Perhaps it's a couple of lines of code to make this work properly and I'm missing something. Please take a look:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import addStaticButton from './images/addStaticBtn.png';
import addButton from './images/addTaskBtn.png';

var todoContainer = document.getElementById('todo');

class AddTaskElement extends Component {

    render() {
        const styling = {
            addTaskContainer: {
                border: "2px solid #000",
                width: "350px",
                cursor: 'pointer',
                boxSizing: 'border-box'
            },
            leftArea: {
                position: 'relative',
                float: 'left',
                marginRight: '20px',
                padding: '12px'
            },
            addStaticBtn: {
                width: '50px',
                height: '50px'
            }
        }

        return (
            <div style={styling.addTaskContainer} onClick={this.props.isAddTaskClicked}  className="addTaskContainer">
                <div style={styling.leftArea} className="leftArea">
                    <img style={styling.addStaticBtn} id="addStaticBtn" alt="addStaticBtn" src={addStaticButton}/>
                </div>
                <div className="rightArea">
                    <h1 id="addTaskText">ADD TASK</h1>
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

class TaskInfo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const styling = {
            taskInfoContainer: {
                border: "2px solid #000",
                boxSizing: 'border-box',
                width: '350px'
            },
            taskNameContainer: {
                padding: '10px',
            },
            taskDescriptionContainer: {
                padding: '10px'
            },
            label: {
                width: '100px',
                display: 'inline-block'
            },
            taskName: {
                width: '220px'
            },
            taskDescription: {
                width: '220px',
                height: '75px'
            },
            addTaskBtn: {
                width: '50px',
                height: '50px'
            },
            addTaskBtnContainer: {
                textAlign: 'center'
            }
        }

        return(
            <div style={styling.taskInfoContainer} className={this.props.taskElementItemClass}>
                <form onSubmit={this.props.formSubmit}>
                    <div className="taskNameContainer" style={styling.taskNameContainer}>
                        <label style={styling.label}>Name: </label>
                        <input id="taskName" style={styling.taskName} name="name" type="text"  />
                    </div>
                    <div style={styling.taskDescriptionContainer} className="taskDescriptionContainer">
                        <label style={styling.label}>Description: </label>
                        <textarea id="taskDescription" style={styling.taskDescription} ></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div style={styling.addTaskBtnContainer}>
                        <input style={styling.addTaskBtn} type="image" src={addButton} alt="Add Task" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class TaskItem extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {/*{this.props.children}*/}
                <p>{this.props.taskItemName}</p>
                <p>{this.props.taskItemDescription}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class TaskList extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        numberOfTasks: 0
    }
    render() {
        const styling = {
            taskListContainer: {
                width: '350px',
                border: '2px solid #000',
                boxSizing: 'border-box',
                textAlign: 'center'
            }
        };

        return(
            <div>
                <div className="taskListContainer" style={styling.taskListContainer}>
                    <p>Task List ({this.props.numberOfTasks})</p>
                    <TaskItem taskItemName={this.props.taskItemName} taskItemDescription={this.props.taskItemDescription} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class Printer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            taskElementItemState: 'hidden',
            taskName: '',
            taskDescription: ''
        }

        this.handleAddTaskClick = this.handleAddTaskClick.bind(this);
        this.handleTaskAdd = this.handleTaskAdd.bind(this);

    }
    handleTaskAdd(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
            taskName: document.getElementById('taskName').value,
            taskDescription: document.getElementById('taskDescription').value
        });
    }
    handleAddTaskClick() {
        this.setState({
           taskElementItemState: this.state.taskElementItemState === 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden'
        });
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <AddTaskElement isAddTaskClicked={this.handleAddTaskClick}/>
                <TaskInfo formSubmit={this.handleTaskAdd} taskElementItemClass={this.state.taskElementItemState}/>
                <TaskList taskItemName={this.state.taskName} taskItemDescription={this.state.taskDescription} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Printer/>, todoContainer);
```

Comment: I'm not seeing an array in your code. Your intuition is correct if you want a list of items you'll need to store that data in an array. What did you try that was unsuccesful?

Comment: Have you read this part of the docs on lists? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: I'm trying to use arrays like here: https://codepen.io/woodman1986/pen/Nbwjwa?editors=0010 . line 198 is the array returned and operations are perfomed in line 143. I console log the output of an array and some value is on the third click (probably I messed sth up with the states) but when I type something else the value is just replaced and not added to an array (i.e. it is still a one-item array)